# Add another level to org-mode visibility cycling

Tags: org-mode, cycling, outline, visibility

The way `S-TAB` (`org-global-cycle`) switches between "top headline -> all headlines -> all content" is great for showing an outline and provide overview, but acts on the full document. Using `TAB` (`org-cycle`) works on a local part of the document, but cycles between "chosen headline -> next headline -> all content".

Thus, `org-cycle` does not provide the same good overview, as all the content is revealed before an outline has been shown.

Is it possible to modify `(org-cycle)` to cycle between four levels, e.g., "chosen headline -> next headline -> all headlines -> all content"?

Comment: My answer in a semi-related thread discusses a way to show all the properties when cycling:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17492723/2112489  I.e., by modifying `org-cycle-internal-local`.  Because `org-mode` answers are a moving target in so far as everyone has different versions and the answer changes from day to day as development continues, I generally only make comments instead of posting answers ....